# Export WKID from shapefile using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system

I am trying to export the WKID for a shapefile using ArcPy, but the data that is generated using the following code doesn't contain the WKID.

For example, when I issue the following:

```
sr = arcpy.Describe(fc).SpatialReference.exportToString()
```

where fc is a feature class, the output is

```
'PROJCS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",0.0],PARAMETER["Auxiliary_Sphere_Type",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]];-20037700 -30241100 148923141.928385;-100000 10000;-100000 
10000;0.001;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision'
```

In ArcGIS Pro, if you select properties->data source for a feature class, it displays the WKID.

How can I export this information?

Comment: Look at the other properties of `arcpy.SpatialReference` -- Note that custom projections might not have a well-known projection code.

Comment: That was it. I just wasn't thinking clearly. `sr.factoryCode` generates what I needed